Rigid foam board under LP Smart Side for noise reduction?
Rigid exterior foam board for noise?
I live in a noisy area. Old house, which has what appears to be pine cladding underneath the original siding. Original siding stripped. Contractor had the house wrapped in tyvek and put LP smart side directly over. Project isn’t quite finished yet, so if there is any time to ask for corrections it is now.
How much noise reduction am I losing by not going with 1/2” rigid foam board (EPS or polyiso$ under LP?

Air gaps and acoustically isolated connections help more than just stuff.  I.e. how you attach the foam board is at least as important as the board itself.  Discussion from someone trying to sell soundproofing.
If you have two rigid layers, you can put a viscoelastic between them.  Viscoelastic substances convert sound to heat.  Look for Green Glue or its competitors.  Note:  despite the name, Green Glue is not an adhesive.  It's more goo than glue.
Mass-loaded vinyl can also help.  Not rigid, it can absorb some of the sound.  Also useful at fencing.
Don't forget the windows.  Perhaps the current windows are better than the walls, but if you improve the walls enough, that could flip.  Or the current windows could be the problem.
